# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" cannot reference .js script in VueJS project but works in 'simple' html/js/css project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a conundrum.

In project #1, I have the following code in my index.html file which brings in a javascript library (d3.js), from a 'js' folder that sits in the same folder as the index.html file.

This works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
```

In project #2, using the exact same line of code in my index.html, and the exact same folder reference, (js folder sitting in index.html) I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Project #2 is a VueJS project that was created following the instructions in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYNjEzcOTOs&t=851s i.e. using Vue CLI.

Project #1 was not set up using a framework, just a 'simple' HTML/Javascript/Css structure.

Screenshot of Project 1 file structure
[image: Project 1 File STru]

Screenshot of Project 2 file structure.
[image]

**My questions is this: Why is the exact same code working for Project 1 but comes up with an error for Project 2, whereby the script cannot find the relevant 'js' subfolder location???**

Comment: Presumably: Because your two projects use two different HTTP servers which are configured differently.

Comment: make sure your text encoding and line-endings are correct. For example I had a similar problem years back only to find out that one js file was using MAC line endings instead of UNIX ones

Comment: This happens when your server returns an error page, e.g. a 404 when the `js/d3.js` is not found. The browser expects JS but gets an HTML error page.

Comment: @Quentin - could you please elaborate on this? I thought that script tag and src parameter should work irrespective of how HTTP server is set up so long as folder structure makes sense?
NikosM. - thanks, I've checked but doesn't seem to be an issue with either.

The js/d3.js file definitely exists, I'm just confused as to why the server can't find it.

Comment: @TheBlake — For a basic HTTP server solely designed to serve static files, yes. You don't appear to have one of those for project 2.